# .htaccess not working when adding one line

Tags: .htaccess

I made a search function with a .htaccess file.
I just added a new line that goes to player.php, but as soon as I added this line the other RewriteRules don't work anymore and the pages all return a Internal Server Error, except for the pages that match the first line.

I added [L] to the RewriteRule to try to stop at the first match, but this doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would.

These are all the RewriteRules I have in my .htaccess file:

```bash
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/.$ /player.php?video_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?network=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?network=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?network=$1&site=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is your `player.php` present in same place as `index.php` in your folder?

Comment: Yes, both these files are in the root of the directory

Comment: ok what URL is working and what is not working, please do let know sample URLs. thank you.

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the rewriting "loops" - after each round, the _new_ rewritten URL gets send through the whole process again. The `L` flag only prevents execution of further rules in the _current_ round. What does the error log say about the actual reason for the 500? Probably that the internal rewrite limit was hit, I suppose - but please go and check.

Comment: You are using `([^/])` in a lot of places there - which would only match _one single_ character, that is not the slash. So do all your `site`, `keyword`, `network` slugs that you need to match there, really only consist of one single character ...?

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Comment: The htaccess lines did contain +, not sure why that didn't show in this post. I made the edit.

These urls work:
//[host]/, //[host]/video/1000/[title]

But as soon as I add the first line in the .htaccess file, these urls don't work
//[host]/[keyword], //[host]/[network]/, //[host]/[network]/[site]/, //[host]/[network]/[keyword]

As soon as I remove that one line, all the urls work, except //[host]/video/1000/[title]

For some reason swapping the place of the 2nd and 3rd line also causes problems, even if there is no /site/ in the url:
//[host]/[keyword]

Comment: @Martinthehun, Kindly add sample urls in your questions only to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: I read the error log and got this back:
`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

I think the htaccess gets in an infinite loop by trying to redirect the index.php, I tried adding this to ignore these urls, but this doesn't work either
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^player.php.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php.*`